# sqlAdmin.backupRuns.list how to set maxresult attribute

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-sql

I have written a Nodejs code on Cloud Functions to create an on-demand backup and delete backup after retention days. However, calling `sqlAdmin.backupRuns.list()` returns a default of only 20 backups.

How do I set the `setMaxResults` attribute? This returns an error stating **method does not exist**.

```
sqlAdmin.backupRuns.list.setMaxResults(100);
```

This is how I'm retrieving all the backups:

```
sqlAdmin.backupRuns.list(request, function(err, response)

sqlAdmin.backupRuns.list.setMaxResults(100);
sqlAdmin.backupRuns.list(request, function(err, response) {
      response.data.items.forEach(element => {
      //do useful

      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `maxResults` as a parameter based on the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/sqladmin/classes/Resource$Backupruns.html#list). For example:

```
params = {
  "project": "PROJECT_NAME",
  "instance": "INSTANCE_ID",
  "maxResults": 100
}
const res = await sqlAdmin.backupRuns.list(params);
console.log(res.data)
```

> INSTANCE_ID is Cloud SQL instance ID. This does not include the project ID.